# Arduino Ethernet parsing XML

Tags: http, get, arduino

I'm using an Arduino Uno and ethernet shield to pull xml data from OpenWeatherMap.org. I have the api link and a key, and it all works fine on the web browser. My code is below, however when I get to reading the response from the GET command, all i get is "ÿ", not anything I would expect.

I can connect to the arduino when using it as a server, and I can ping it from command prompt so I know it is on the network and the board is not at fault, so it must be something with my code. I have followed the tutorial on the arduino site and loaded the example to GET data, but this also does not work, all I get is a "did not connect" message.

Can someone please look over my code and see what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: I have added the extra loop to print all the xml data, however the program still gets stuck on the `while(!client.available());`. If i comment it out, I get to the "waiting for server response" but never any further than that. I have checked that the arduino si on the same subnet mask as all the other devices in the network.

```
// Based on:
// Read Yahoo Weather API XML
// 03.09.2012
// http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=121992.0
//


#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <TextFinder.h>



int cityID=2644487; //Lincoln, UK
byte mac[] = {0x00, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDE, 0x02};
byte ip[] = {192, 168, 1, 89};
byte gateway[] = {192, 168, 1, 254};
byte subnet[] = {255, 255, 255, 0};
//Open weather map xml
char server[] = "http://api.openweathermap.org";
int port = 80; //usually 80 for http.
char APIkey[33] = "HIDDENAPIKEY";


EthernetClient client;
char temperature[30];


void setup()
{
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Initialising...");

  // Start Ethernet
  if(!Ethernet.begin(mac)){//if DHCP does not automatically connect
     Serial.println("Invalid Connection");
  }


    Serial.println("");
    Serial.print("Connecting to OWM server using cityID: ");
    Serial.println(cityID);
    Serial.print("Using API key: ");
    Serial.println(APIkey); 

  if (client.connect(server,port))
  {
    client.println("GET /data/2.5/weather?id=2644487&appid=HIDDENAPIKEY&mode=xml&units=metric HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("HOST: api.openweathermap.org");
    client.println();
    Serial.println("Connected to XML data.");

   while(!client.available()); //wait for client data to be available
   Serial.println("Waiting for server response...");
   while(client.available()){

      char c = client.read();
      Serial.println(c);
   }
  } 


}

void loop()
{

}
```

Comment: Why you print single character only? You have to get entire response to see what happens.

Keep in mind that you need to parse out headers from response. To find this, search for \r\n\r\n sequence. After that you have your body data with XML

Comment: Is your computer on the same network and able to access the internet? If so, please go to cmd and type in the command "ipconfig" . Check the subnet mask on your Arduino and be sure that it matches your computer. If it is different than other parts of your network, you could have only partial connectivity.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the code after your suggestion. I have also checked the subnet mask, all devices are on the same subnet, I've edited the original post to explain.

Answer (score 0):

For start, your Host header is wrong, use only domain name:

```
client.println("HOST: api.openweathermap.org");
```

Second problem I see here is that you do not read entire response from server but only one char.
You have to wait for response data to be available, after that read all the data and parse it or print at start.

This part is wrong:

```
char c = client.read();
Serial.println(c);
```

Should be something similar to:

```
while (!client.available());  //Wait client data to be available
while (client.available()) {  //Print all the data
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.println(c);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, i've added a few extra serial prints to see where the code gets stuck, seems to be it doesn't get a response from the GET command. I never get the serial print of "Waiting for server response"


    Serial.println("Connected to XML data.");
   
     while(!client.available()); //wait for client data to be available
     Serial.println("Waiting for server response...");
     while(!client.available()){
   
      char c = client.read();
      Serial.println(c);
    }

Comment: I have corrected second while loop. There should not be ! because you are looping while data available to read.

Comment: Thanks, it did seem odd that it was the same loop! however it still gets stuck on waiting for a response from the GET command, i've edited the original post to clarify

Comment: @tilz0R I am not convinced by your code, suppose that the server is sending 100 bytes, as soon as the first byte arrives you check 'client.available()' and it is equal to one hence you get past the first loop and you enter the second loop. Now you read a character, but for whatever reasons, the next byte coming from the server isn't placed in the incoming buffer before you check again 'client.available()': now you leave the loop and you fail to read all of the incoming data.  [continues]

Comment: [continues] If somehow you put everything into an external loop and you handle it properly, then you can deal with this situation with no problems.. however in this case the instruction 'while(!client.available());' appears to be rather pointless.

Comment: This is general principle. In real system this code should be placed in loop and checked every time if something new. This is the reason why Arduino is bad idea ;)

Comment: @tilz0R why, arduino doesn't have loops?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin It has loops, of coarse, but you have to do other jobs as well. And reading data fast will empty the receive buffer when waiting for more data. When you are client, you don't know how much data you can expect until you receive content-length header from HTTP (if you use HTTP). If you don't receive that header or you don't use HTTP, you have no chance to know number of bytes you will receive.

Comment: @tilz0R I agree, but how's that an Arduino problem?